# Tensorboard Audio Summary Files Empty

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I'm trying to periodically add audio samples to Tensorboard, which are independent of the computation graph. I'm working in Keras, and have created a custom callback to log audio files at the end of each epoch.

Everything seems to be working fine, except that the audio files are empty, that is, they have a length of zero and nothing plays.

Below is a minimum viable example of the Callback which reproduces the problem.

```
class TensorBoardAudio(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):

        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOG_DIR)

        data, fs = sf.read('/path/to/wavfile.wav', dtype='float32')

        audio = tf.Summary.Audio(encoded_audio_string=data.tobytes(),
                             content_type='audio/wav',
                             sample_rate=fs,
                             length_frames=len(data))

        summary = tf.Summary(value=[tf.Summary.Value(tag='test', audio=audio)])
        writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)

        writer.flush()
        writer.close()
```

I can reproduce audio from the `data.tobytes()`, so I know there's data being passed in, I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing tensorboard via Chrome instead of any other browser? I encountered the same issue (empty audio files) in Safari, but Chrome worked just fine without making any changes to my code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer is better suited as a comment. Please use the comment section under the question for that.